# Google App Engine: Encoding type for CSV?

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, notepad++

I am trying to upload data using `appcfg.py upload_data`. My CSV was encoded as ANSI, but Alex Martelli said that it should probably be UTF-8. So I switched to that (using Notepad++).

This hit an error at the very first character of my file:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So then I switch back to ANSI, I get this:

```
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Hmmm... Looks like someone else had a similar problem [here](http://markmail.org/message/pmfbp5j37kbuo5ca). How would I remove the newlines at the end of the each line most efficiently using Notepad++? Or is there something else I'm supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when fetching files over HTTP, which could be UTF-8. I fixed it by first converting the string to unicode using:

```
unicodecontent = unicode(content, 'utf8')
```

Then every time I need to access it as ascii I would encode back as UTF-8:

```
unicodecontent.encode('utf_8')
```

This worked for me when trying to parse an XML file with ElementTree (fromstring)